# If the Gradle conventional directory structure for Java is changed, where do the .class files get created?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

If the conventional directory structure, src\main\java is changed to src\java\main
then where would the .class files be placed?The `gradle build` command gives the message 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL, But how to find the location of the .class files to run the application.

What is the way to find where the .class files have got created?

Comment: Brute-force solution: `find . -name '*.class'`.

Comment: Are you changing the config, or just putting the source in a different directory

Comment: @jrtapsell, The sources were put into the last folder of the package structure.The package structure started after the folder /main/, just like this /src/java/main/package structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just put the source files into another directory, so that the layout does not follow the Maven convention (`src/main/java` or `src/test/java` for tests), Gradle won't use them, because it can't find them.

*Convention over configuration* does not mean, that there is no configuration, it just means that you don't need to specifiy it, **if** you follow the convention. Gradle is (by default) configured to compile `*.java` files in `src/main/java`. All other files will be ignored (for compilation).

You can however break the convention and configure your source file location manually:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/java/main']
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't alter any other configuration (e.g. properties of the `compileJava` task), class files will still be located at `<project-dir>/build/classes/main`, where `main` is the name of the source set (which is the default).

Please note, that `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` does not mean that anything was built, but only that no task failed. It is perfectly fine for Gradle to not find (and therefore not compile) any source files at all. But if you use the command-line option `–console=plain`, the `compileJava` task should report `NO-SOURCE`.

Comment: By mistake, I had created the directory structure  projectroot\src\java\main\package structure\, and the source files were put into the last folder of the package structure.When the build file was run, a BUILD SUCCESSFUL message was displayed, though the build folder was created, no classes folder was to be seen, only libs and temp were present.

Comment: lu koerfer,  just as you said.The compileJava task reports NO-SOURCE gradle --console=plain build :compileJava NO-SOURCE